# Quickly navigate through a cascade of otherwise empty directories in helm

Tags: helm, directories

I'd like to be able to quickly skip to the bottom of a cascade of otherwise empty directories. Consider the following directory structure:

```
foo/
  bar/
    baz/
      a.txt
      b.txt
```

If I were in `foo/` with `helm-find-files`, I'd like to get to `baz/` quickly. I can think of two possible solutions.

1. Somehow configure helm to provide a shortcut to `baz/` when in `foo/`, so the find file buffer  might look like:

   ```
   .
   ..
   bar/baz
   bar
   ```

   And `bar/baz` is maybe marked in a different color.
2. Have the active selection automatically set to the first member of the current directory instead of `.`, i.e.

   ```
   .      <-- selection is usually here after entering a new directory
   ..
   one/   <-- instead, automatically highlight this
   two/
   three.txt
   ```

   That way, `baz/` is two keypresses from `foo/`.

If I could implement both of these then I'd really be flying. I tried `helm-ff-auto-update-initial-value` but did not find it useful. You still have to type the first three letters of the directory to enter it automatically. Actually typing even just one character of the directory is not satisfactory. Hiding `.` and `..` has been proposed but is a hack and not supported by the developers, see [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1863) and [here](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/924).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do #2.

```
(defun tsj/helm-ff-skip-past-dots ()
  (if (and (equal "Find Files" (assoc-default 'name (helm-get-current-source)))
       (s-ends-with? "/." (helm-get-selection)))
  (with-helm-window
    (forward-line 2)
    (helm-mark-current-line))))

(with-eval-after-load 'helm-files
  (advice-add 'helm--update-move-first-line
      :after #'tsj/helm-ff-skip-past-dots))
```